# Possibly Null Reference on MVC Property

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

Actually in my ASP.NET Core 7 MVC code, I have a view model that takes an optional `Address` property:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Address? Address { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to use it within ASP.NET Core MVC, I get the warning

> CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference

View:

```
<th scope="col">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.First().Address.State)</th>
```

What is the recommended way to call this property without any compiler warning?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided?  Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [! (null-forgiving) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving):

`@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.First().Address!.State)`

Check [Microsoft sample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/d8b029a127d7b220e056c799c7324979b5990937/aspnetcore/razor-pages/index/6.0sample/RazorPagesContacts/Pages/Customers/Delete.cshtml#L16) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to use it within ASP.NET Core MVC, I get the warning

Actually, this is expected behavior based on your possible nullable defination on Address? and compiler is expecting there might be a change of null occurrence which compiler warning as following:

[image]

Thus, compiler wanting to set a nullability check before the very statement.

> What is the recommended way to call this property without any compiler
> warning?

As per our [official guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#possible-dereference-of-null), you can simply get rid of your warnings by putting a null checking `!` after Address property like: `First().Address!.State` which other contributors already shown you.

```
<th scope="col">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.First().Address!.State)</th>
```

[image]

[image]

**Note:** I am trying to enhance the answer because we have particular document for [CS8602 warning code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#possible-dereference-of-null) which is [Dereference of a possibly null reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#possible-dereference-of-null) and my sole purpose is to refer you [correct document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#possible-dereference-of-null).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to explicitly check the first returned element for null

```
<th scope="col">
@{
    var address = Model.First().Address;
    if (address != null)
    {
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(_ => address.State)
    }
}
</th>
```